# Conditional Query depending on parameters

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-data-jpa, repository

I'm doing a React + Springboot application. In some part of the app I have a four selectors and a button to search("Buscar").
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyHc7.png)

What I'm trying to do is a conditional query depending on which values are selected.
With this code below I can do the query if all the values are filled but if some is missing it throws an error (
[Current Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yTtn.png) )

I think it may be with the Specifiaction or something like that not sure yet

Comment: Please include all the information for your question in the question, do not hide them behind links.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom queries in spring data jpa using specifications

Here you conditionally add create criteria queries.
ref:

https://reflectoring.io/spring-data-specifications/

https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

This can help you with all your custom permutations and combinations.

Comment: y, im trying that but i run into the same problem, do I have to create 24 IF condition to evaluate every combination? Or theres some way that Specification can resolve it?